# get some data of user's friends - Facebook / FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-friends

I'm creating an app where user will be able to select some of his friends then the app will do some job on the selected friends.

My question is =->
Can I directly write this FQL?

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = $friendUID
```

Or Do I need to write something like this?

```
SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and UID = $friendUID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

it showed that both are correct

Answer (score 0):

Both queries are same.

```
1. SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = $friendUID 

2. SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE 
uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) and UID = $friendUID
```

In 1st query, you are directly accessing data by directly Friends Id.

In 2nd query, you are checking uid is also friend or not and then accessing data.

**You can use 1st query to check any user's data though he/she might not be your friend.** For uid, name, pic_square there is no any requirement that user is your friend or app user. You can get that information of any Facebook user.